# mgo mongodb read / write example

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am new to mgo and would need some help with this:
I can succesfully connect and print out db name, collection name and number of item is collection, but do not know how to print out contents in it and write back.
What would be an equivalent in mgo to the below mongodb shell commands?

```
- db.coll.find()
- document=({"user_id" : "xxx","password" :"xxx"....});
- db.coll.insert(document)
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

//const MongoDb details
const (
    hosts      = "mongodb.xxx:27017"
    database   = "myinfo"
    username   = "xxxxx"
    password   = "start123"
    collection = "userdetails"
)

func main() {

    info := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{hosts},
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
        Database: database,
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    }

    session, err1 := mgo.DialWithInfo(info)
    if err1 != nil {
        panic(err1)
    }

    col := session.DB(database).C(collection)
    datab := session.DB(database)

    count, err2 := col.Count()
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }

    fmt.Println("Database Name:", datab.Name)
    fmt.Println("Collection FullName:", col.FullName)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Documents count: %d", count))

}
```

Here is a version that works:

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

//const MongoDb details
const (
    hosts      = "xxx:27017"
    database   = "myinfo"
    username   = "xxxx"
    password   = "start123"
    collection = "userdetails2"
)


type UserDetails struct {
        _id        bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
        name    string
        phone   string
}

func main() {

    info := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{hosts},
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
        Database: database,
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    }

    session, err1 := mgo.DialWithInfo(info)
    if err1 != nil {
        panic(err1)
    }

    col := session.DB(database).C(collection)
    datab := session.DB(database)

    count, err2 := col.Count()
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }


        fmt.Println("Database Name:", datab.Name)
        fmt.Println("Collection FullName:", col.FullName)
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Documents count: %d", count))

        var userDetail []bson.M
        _ = col.Find(nil).All(&userDetail)
        for _, v := range userDetail {
        fmt.Println(v)
}

}
```

Comment: My next question is about write:
err = col.Insert(&UserDetails{name: "Example", phone: "65 234 4321"})
only insert ids, but not the actual data
map[_id:ObjectIdHex("5b052ff3cd1d98d5dda89ed8")]
what am I missing?

Comment: Found the error:
type UserDetails struct {
        _id        bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
        name    string
        phone   string
}
name should be Name
phone should be Phone
and write also works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type UserDetails struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    UserId string `bson:"user_id"`
    Password string `bson:"password"`
}
userDetails := []UserDetails{}
query := bson.M{
    "user_id": "xxx",
    "password" :"xxx"
}
err := col.Find(query).All(&userDetails)
if err != nil {
    return
}
for _, userDetail := range userDetails {
    fmt.Println(userDetail)
}
```

I haven't test this code. It's just an example.

Comment: Anybody else with something tested?

Comment: This is what I am getting:
Database Name: myinfo
Collection FullName: myinfo.userdetails
Documents count: 2
{           }
so it is empty

Answer (score 0):

Here's fairly simple example of mgo package: https://gist.github.com/border/3489566

I would suggest to go through the official documentation for details and references. https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.Find

Note that `"gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"` package is no longer maintained. `https://github.com/globalsign/mgo` is a fork of that package and maintained by community.